# Why does the global variable value show up as undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, undefined

```js
const mode = "portfolio";

document.addEventListener('keydown',(event) => {
  console.log(event.key);
  if(event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'ArrowDown'){
    modeToggle();
  }
})

const modeToggle = function() {
  console.log(`mode toggle called, current mode is ${this.mode}`);
  if(this.mode == "portfolio") {
    this.mode ="blog";
  } else if(this.mode == "blog"){
    this.mode ="portfolio";
  }
  console.log(this.mode);
}
```

`this.mode` comes up as 'undefined' in the console log.

Can you please help me understand why the this.mode variable's value is undefined?
Thanks :)

P.S. - First question on stackflow :P

Comment: `this` refers to an object it belongs to. Does the constant `mode` belong to any object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `this` is in an event handler, it is referencing the object that triggered the event, in this case that would normally be the `document`. But, because you used an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as the callback, `this` is not actually modified from whatever it was referencing prior to the invocation, which in this case actually was `window`, however because you used `const`, your variable got block level scope and didn't bind as a `window` property [as stated in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description):

> This declaration creates a constant whose scope can be either global
> or local to the block in which it is declared. Global constants do not
> become properties of the window object, unlike var variables.

**To access a Global, don't use `this`** or, if you wanted to use this with `window`, declare the variable with `var` so you don't get block level scope.

Also, if you want to be able to modify the variable, don't declare it with `const` (constant).

```js
// If you want to be able to modify a variable value,
// you can't have it declared as a constant. And, by
// declaring with const or let, you create block level
// scope and don't actually create a new property on
// the Global object, but with var, you do.
var mode = "portfolio";

document.addEventListener('keydown',(event) => {
  // Within an event handler, "this" is a reference to the
  // object that triggered the event. But, within an Arrow
  // function, this is unchanged from whatever it had been
  // prior to the invocation of the arrow function. In this
  // case, the window, but if your Global is declared with
  // const or let, you'll get block scope and won't create
  // a true global property. With "var" (as I've shown above)
  // you will:
  console.log(this.mode, event.key);
  if(event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'ArrowDown'){
    modeToggle();
  }
})

const modeToggle = function() {
  console.log(`mode toggle called, current mode is ${mode}`);
  if(mode == "portfolio") {
    mode ="blog";
  } else if(mode == "blog"){
    mode ="portfolio";
  }
  console.log(mode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand my mistake now. Your solution worked as I wanted it to.

Comment: @SirTammutHatmaker You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top left and also to up vote.

Comment: Done. Your updated answer makes it very clear. Thanks again! :D